# Как сделать единую границу у нескольких блоков с border-radius

Tags: html, css, border

Пытаюсь сделать единую границу у нескольких соседних блоков в виде змейки. Если бы углы были прямые, то всё было бы просто. Но углы должны быть скруглённые. Пробую делать так:

```css
div {
  width: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  border-top: none;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Но не некоторых углах стыки явно видны :( Можно ли как-то исправить это? Или, может быть, есть вообще другое решение для подобной задачи?

Comment: А использовать svg не подойдёт?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в этих блоках будет содержимое, это можно совместить с svg? я просто в svg не силен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPD: `overflow:hidden;` идёт на помощь

Как выяснилось, непрозрачный фон не подходит по условиям задачи. Тогда завернём каждый блок в ещё один и дадим обёрткам свойство `overflow:hidden;`. Отрицательный верхний маржин уведёт верхнюю границу за пределы обёртки, и обёртка её спрячет.

```css
.snake-border > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.snake-border > div > div {          /* 6. */
  width: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  margin-top: -2px;                  /* 2. */
}

.snake-border > div:nth-of-type(1) > div {
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;                  /* 1. */
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.snake-border > div:nth-of-type(2n+2) > div {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;                 /* 4. */
}

.snake-border > div:nth-of-type(2n+3) > div {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.snake-border > div:last-of-type > div {  /* 5. */
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="snake-border">
  <div><div></div></div>
  <div><div></div></div>
  <div><div></div></div>
  <div><div></div></div>
  <div><div></div></div>
  <div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

### Белый фон делает чёрное дело

1. Верхнюю границу спрячем только у первого блока. У остальных этого делать не надо, иначе пропадёт часть скругления на углу блока.
2. Приподнимем блоки на ширину границы, чтобы в каждой паре блоков верхняя граница нижнего соседа накладывалась на нижнюю границу верхнего.
3. А чтобы одну из наложившихся границ всё-таки не было видно, назначим блокам непрозрачный фон. (По умолчанию [`background-clip`](https://webref.ru/css/background-clip) имеет значение `border-box`, и фон заползает под границы.)
4. Можно поиграть левым отступом, чтобы пунктир удачнее обрывался на переходах между блоками.
5. Можно сделать, чтобы у последнего блока граница уходила вниз вертикально, — так же, как начинается у первого.
6. И поместим всё внутрь блока с классом, а то даже сниппет добавляет к вёрстке служебные блоки.

```css
.snake-border > div {                /* 6. */
  width: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  margin-top: -2px;                  /* 2. */
  background: white;                 /* 3. */
}

.snake-border > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;                  /* 1. */
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.snake-border > div:nth-of-type(2n+2) {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;                 /* 4. */
}

.snake-border > div:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.snake-border > div:last-of-type {   /* 5. */
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="snake-border">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: непрозрачный фон не подойдет, увы (

Comment: Тогда можно каждый блок с границей завернуть в блок с `overflow:hidden;`. Отрицательный верхний маржин уведёт верхнюю границу за пределы обёртки, и обёртка её спрячет.

Comment: @humster_spb Добавил второй вариант решения, проверьте